# Boolean Expressions with DeMorgan’s law

Tags: boolean-operations

I need help using De Morgan's law to derive an expression that is equivalent to

('A + B + 'C)D but uses only AND and NOT operations (but no OR operation).

Comment: What *is* De Morgan's law? [Read up about it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws) - and the available transformations from OR to AND should be quite clear. Note that DM only *directly* covers `P + Q` or `P * Q`. Other [boolean algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra) - i.e. the associativity law - can be used to construct/deconstruct the expressions. Likewise, a TTL could be generated as a part of a proof showing that DM applies just as well to `P + Q + R`.

Answer (score 2):

First, `('A + B + 'C) = ''('A + B + 'C) = '(A * 'B * C)`.
So the result is, `('(A * 'B * C)) * D`.